# Angular universal SSR - console error TypeError: this._removeListenerFns.pop(...) is not a function

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I am trying to setup ssr on my angular project but i keep getting this error and not sure how to fix this or understand what is the cause.

Has anyone seen something similar?

when i look at the main.js file that the ssr command has built it refers to a LocationStrategy class and references a base href

Comment: I got it, but no clue as to what it is

Comment: Same issue here, you found any solution?

Comment: i updated the libraries for angular universal / anything needed for the setup and removed node_modules and installed everything again and it seemed to go away